# The app doesnt remember shared preferences values

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am working on an Android app and the app is seperated into two lets say for men and women. The user chooses which part of activity it wants to oen. For example, if the user a man, he chooses man part, if she a woman, she clicks woman button and the page for women appears.

To avoid bothering users, I put a check box and I said remember my choise next time. Very common thing...

I tried to use shared preferences for this, but it doesnt work. It asks the question every time the app open. Here are the codes:

**The Activity I ask the question**

```
View checkBoxView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.activity_menu, null);
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) checkBoxView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked){
                SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                prefEditor.putString("Remember", "Checked");
                prefEditor.commit();
            }
        }
});
```

**The splash activity which decides to ask question or to open the chosen activty before**

```
SharedPreferences sp = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
                    String str1 = sp.getString("Remember", "");
                    String str2 = sp.getString("Hacc", "");

                    if (str1 == "") {
                        Intent menuIntent = new Intent(
                                "com.uygulama.hacc.MenuActivity");
                        startActivity(menuIntent);
                    }
                    else{
                        if(str2 == "Hacc" ){
                            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(
                                    "com.uygulama.hacc.HaccActivity");
                            startActivity(mainIntent);
                        }
                        else{
                            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(
                                    "com.uygulama.hacc.UmreActivity");
                            startActivity(mainIntent);
                        }
                    }
```

I am new on Android so, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're using 2 different activities to write and read shared preferences. If you call `getPreferences` from `Activity`, it opens preferences associates with that activity. Try changing the access to preferences to:

```
// read
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
String str1 = settings.getString("Remember", "");

// write
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString("Remember", "Checked");
editor.commit();
```

Also, when comparing strings, use `equals`:

```
str2.equals("Hacc")
```

otherwise you compare references.

Comment: getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); doesnt work. It is may be getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());? OK you edited it. Let me try again.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that too. Edited my answer.

Comment: Edited again, put full answer

Comment: Unfourtunately no.. Trying to some other lines. Doo you have any other solution

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37940/discussion-between-szymon-and-user2870)

Answer (score 1):

You should use shared preferences instead of getPreferences to share preferences between activities.

From Android doc:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

> Activity persistent state is managed with the method
>   getPreferences(int), allowing you to retrieve and modify a set of
>   name/value pairs associated with the activity. To use preferences that
>   are shared across multiple application components (activities,
>   receivers, services, providers), you can use the underlying
>   Context.getSharedPreferences() method to retrieve a preferences object
>   stored under a specific name. (Note that it is not possible to share
>   settings data across application packages -- for that you will need a
>   content provider.)

Answer (score 0):

your saving in your first class lacks of a namespace inside your SharedPreferences.

try something like:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("AppName", MODE_PRIVATE);
prefs.edit().putBoolean("Remember", true).commit();
```

and retrieve it with:

```
SharedPreferences sPrefs = getSharedPreferences("AppName", 0);
Boolean bCheck = sPrefs.getBoolean("Remember", false);
```